# Canonical name for Iseq from "Implementing Functional Languages: a tutorial"

Tags: serialization, miranda

In Simon Peyton Jones's ["Implementing Functional Languages: a tutorial"](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/research/wp-content/uploads/1992/01/student.pdf), a data structure for efficient string building called `Iseq`, also referred to as `iseq` and `iseqRep`. This can be found by searching through the document.

Is this `Iseq` name a canonical abbrevation for something? What does the "i" prefix refer to? I'm wondering this because I wonder if this is more widely used, and I can't find it anywhere in the literature.

I've been looking elsewhere for anything with the name, and the only eponymous structure is Clojure's `ISeq`, which is a very different thing. The two best guesses I have at the moment are:

- The "i" was completely arbitrary, and used as a prefix to identify all related functions.
- The "i" might stand for "indented sequence"? This is pretty much the only "i" that I could think of.

Comment: I don't believe this question should be off-topic, since I am asking for a canonical name, rather than opinions on what this acronym could be. The tags are somewhat off-topic but the best I could think of for this topic; `Iseq` is related to serialization and the tutorial is written in Miranda.